# Complexity of nested loop with iteration in multiple of 2

Tags: data-structures

Is `O(log(n!))` complexity of this nested loop!

[image]

Comment: why n! .......?

Comment: I am just asking?, I don't actually know

Comment: or it can be O(nlog(n))

Comment: Please take the time to *write the code* in your question. An image of hand-written code is not a good substitute.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop executes log(i) times for each value of i.

So it becomes:

```
log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + log(4) ... + log(n)
```

Which is O(n * log(n)).